Why aren't we using compressed air cars?
Today cars are predominantly powered by an internal combustion engine burning liquid fuels, electricity from a battery or both. Niche cars may use compressed methane or compressed hydrogen.
Electric cars require an expensive battery and expensive power electronics. They are different from internal combustion engine cars in a very major way, but if the battery costs can be reduced, can prove to be a giant leap in mobility.
However, there's a way that allows cars to be powered by grid electricity in a way that doesn't require as major changes to the drivetrain as electric cars require. The internal "combustion" engine can be run with compressed air. The fuel tank is replaced by a compressed air tank, and compressed air then runs the engine that doesn't require any spark plugs or exhaust system parts.
As far as I understand, compressed air cars have been tested. The technology is not rocket science. But yet we can't see any commercial cars that would utilize the technology. Why not? Why is a compressed air car such a bad idea that it isn't available in the way niche cars like hydrogen fuel cell vehicles are?

Have you ever wrestled a K-type gas cylinder into position? They weigh a lot for not much gas inside because of engineering requirements (ASME Pressure vessel standards for instance). Real world compressed air cars are really small with short range.

There are two reasons I know why compressed air isn't a useful source of motive power.
Loss of pressure.
When air is released from the tank, the reservoir cools, and less pressure is available. So performance drops, even without the loss of pressure due to the tank being depleted. Whereas the performance of an ICE is constant right up until 'empty'.
Energy density.
The energy density of compressed air is only a tiny fraction of petroleum. The link states

Petroleum (gas): 34.2 MJ/L
Compressed air: 0.2 MJ/L


Compressed air cars are not generally available, because the technology suffers from a fatal flaw. Compressed air cars are charged simply by compressing air, but the charging is done many hours or even days before the car is driven.
When air is compressed fast, it undergoes adiabatic compression. Part of the energy is stored in the compressed air and part of the energy is stored into heating the compressed air.
Because the charging is done many hours or even days before the car is driven, the heat in the compressed air has time to dissipate. So although the fast charging was done with adiabatic compression, the end result is similar to isothermal compression, in that the temperature at start and at end (after heat dissipation) is the same. I'm not experienced enough in thermodynamics to say whether it's only similar to isothermal compression, or actually equivalent to isothermal compression.
Then when the car is driven, the energy in the compressed air is utilized very fast. It undergoes adiabatic expansion where it cools. The problem is, this cooling robs the efficiency of the compressed air engine. Also because the expansion is adiabatic and not isothermal, the part of the energy that was lost into the heating of the surrounding environment is lost forever.
If a car is driven very slow, let's say at walking speed in level ground, theoretically the energy usage rate could be so low that a very big heat exchanger could change the adiabatic expansion into isothermal expansion, where the expansion is able to utilize the heat that was lost into the surroundings again.
But that's not how cars are driven. Cars are driven often very fast, often up hills too. Acceleration of the big >1000 kg object is fast, so lots of energy is used in a very short timeframe. There is no big enough heat exchanger that could allow isothermal expansion to happen quickly enough. So it's adiabatic expansion only, and adiabatic expansion doesn't utilize the part of the energy that was lost to surroundings as heat.
Compressed air systems have been used in grid energy storage. According to Wikipedia, the McIntosh, Alabama compressed air grid energy storage system requires 2.5 MJ of electricity and 1.2 MJ of natural gas used for reheating for 1 MJ of energy output. That's a terribly poor energy efficiency, even lower than hydrogen vehicles. Note the natural gas for reheating is necessary, since some way to heat the cooling expanding air is needed.
Because of this need for heating, a compressed air energy storage system should be viewed only as a more efficient way to utilize fuels, not as some fuel-free way like what electric batteries are. And if you already have fuels on board, it's just simpler to use those fuels for all of the propelling energy.

I think you're missing the bigger picture of why they aren't being used, that being, you can't store enough compressed air to get the vehicle anywhere significant. A tank of gas (petrol) or a fully charged battery can easily get a car from 4-500 miles of range. You'd have to have a storage tank larger than the vehicle itself to get anything close to that much range using compressed air.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm not entirely convinced range is the full reason. 200 miles is plenty for an EV and that requires 19 liters of gasoline, or 154 MJ of energy after 25% efficiency. At 700 bar (used for Toyota Mirai), 154 MJ requires 0.4 cubic meters of storage (isothermal example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed-air_energy_storage). My car has probably around 10 cubic meters of space.

Of course, at lower pressure like the 70 bar the Wikipedia example had, you need more space. But 700 bar is perfectly well achievable, since Toyota Mirai uses 700 bar for hydrogen.

...and of course, real compressed air cars don't use isothermal expansion but adiabatic expansion which would require more storage than 0.4 cubic meters for isothermal expansion. But indeed, isothermal vs adiabatic was the entire point of my answer: if isothermal expansion can't be achieved, compressed air cars aren't realistic.

I didn't say "full" reason, just a bigger reason. It would suck trying to carry around a pressurized tank to do the deed ... even at 700bar, that would still require a lot of space. Carrying around the amount of fuel needed to produce the same result can be done in a much smaller space.

Well it's true that for example 700 bar hydrogen in Toyota Mirai takes 122 liters, and the hypothetical isothermal expansion compressed air car would require 400 liters. But then again, batteries are big too and we have found a way to store 100 kWh of batteries in cars. According to one source, Tesla original Model S pack is 245Wh/l, so 100 kWh of batteries may require even the 408 liters, by the way, more than 122 liters of hydrogen in Toyota Mirai, and similar in size to a decent compressed air car. 100 kWh packs are present in many EVs.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I sure know a lot of people who have an air compressor in their garage that can run continuously. Sure, they have a little heat exchanger, but not nearly what you seem to be thinking.

@JonCuster But a continuously running air compressor is not an isothermal compressor. As you compress air, it heats up.

Sure, and a little heat exchanger cools it down. My lab has compressed air supplied by a big compressor in the facilities area. I can run compressed air all day every day.  But in a car you have a tank of compressed air, already at ambient temperature. You pull some out at pressure to perform some PV work to move the vehicle. Nothing in the vehicle cares about how the air got compressed in the first place, just that there is air under pressure to use to create mechanical work.

I'm sure the driver of the vehicle cares about the fact that the air expansion is adiabatic, not isothermal. As air expands, it cools down. That robs your range away. If there was a huge heat exchanger (but you can't have such a huge heat exchanger), it could be isothermal expansion that wouldn't rob your range away.

@juhist - I would suggest that 99% of drivers in the world don't know the difference between adiabatic and isothermal.
